# Prove $\mathbb{P}(\sum_{i=1}^kX_i=k)<1$ given i.i.d random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{k}$ be i.i.d. random variables, such that $k\in\mathbb{N}\ (k>0)$ and $X_i\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ for all $i\in[1,k]$. It is given that $p_1\equiv\mathbb{P}(X_i=1)<1$ for all $i\in[1,k]$. Prove:

$$\mathbb{P}(\sum_{i=1}^kX_i=k)<1$$

---

Intuitively, I understand why this is correct. But I'm trying to prove this **rigorously**. The best I could do is:

$$\mathbb{P}(\sum_{i=1}^kX_i=k)\leq\mathbb{P}(\bigcup_{i=1}^k\{X_i\geq1\})=\sum_{i=1}^k\mathbb{P}(X_i\geq1)=k-\sum_{i=1}^k\mathbb{P}(X_i=0)$$

But this doesn't help, of course. I have been trying to find the connection between the sum and the probability $p_1$, but without success. I am also trying to avoid brute-forcing this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By $\mathbb{P}[X_i=1]<1$, there is some $x \neq 1$ such that $\mathbb{P}[X_i = x] > 0$. There may  be in fact many such values of $x$, but fix one of them. As the $X_i$ are i.i.d., we have
$$ \mathbb{P} [X_1+\ldots+ X_k \neq k] \geq \mathbb{P}[X_1+\ldots + X_k = kx] \geq \prod_{i=1}^k\mathbb{P}[X_i =x] > 0. $$
The first inequality above is due to the fact that $x\neq 1$, so that $kx \neq k$.

Comment: This is brilliant! I would never think to do this. Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome!